# Partitioning $10$ people in halves with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

A railway carriage will accommodate $5$ passengers on each side (one side faces the engine, and one side faces backwards). In how many ways can $10$ persons take their seats when two of them decline to face the engine, and a third cannot travel backwards?

So the side facing the engine has 8 potential passengers to choose from, and the side facing the back has 9 potential passengers to choose from.

$^8C_5\cdot^9C_5=^8C_3\cdot^9C_4=\dfrac{8\cdot7\cdot6}{3\cdot2\cdot1}\cdot\dfrac{9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6}{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}=7056$

Since there are $10$ seats in total, the final answer would be $7056\cdot10!$

But the correct answer is $504000$. So my understanding of the question is way off the mark.

Comment: You can do sanity checks : if there is no constraint, the total number of choices is $10!$ ; we have some constraints, so we should obtain less than $10!$ , and you obtain $7056 \times 10!$ ... it is wrong.  In your process, each new constraint multiplys the previous total by a new factor greater than $1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An easy method**

"Two of them decline to face the engine": $\binom{5}{2}2!$ ways to choose their seats and to order them.

"A third person cannot travel backwards": $\binom{5}{1}$ ways to choose the seat.

To arrange the rest of the people: $7!$ ways.

Multiply all these together to get $504000$.

**Fixing your method**

Let's say you want to choose the non-restricted people first (which you tried to do, incorrectly):

*Facing backwards*

Number of ways to choose the seats that contain non-restricted people facing backwards: $\binom{5}{3}$

Number of ways to choose non-restricted people facing backwards, and to order them: $\binom{7}{3}3!$

Number of ways to order the two people who have to face backwards: $2!$

*Facing engine*

Number of ways to choose the seats that contain non-restricted people facing engine: $\binom{5}{4}$.

Number of ways to choose non-restricted people facing engine, and to order them: $1\cdot 4!$ ("$1$" because we have already chosen everyone else, so the way to choose these people is fixed).

Number of ways to order the person who has to face the engine: $1!$

Multiply everything together to get $504000$.